# How to convert Image object to base64 on background thread in Swift?

Tags: swift, image

I have a function where I select Image from cameraroll and I need to convert it to base64 string to send to an API. On the main thread this is blocking UI so want to do it on a background thread
So I first convert it in a function to a UIImage and then to base64 however it crashes since calling into SwiftUI on a non-main thread is not supported

I can't convert from Image to UIImage on a background thread.
How to get Image to base64?

Snippet code from my SwiftUI View

```swift
if selectedImage != nil {
                            uuid = UUID().uuidString
                            let backgroundContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.newBackgroundContext()
                            //generatin the base64 can take a while so lets do this in the background thread
                            backgroundContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
                            DispatchQueue.background(background: {
                     
                             print ("TODO THIS IMAGE PROCESSING")
                                let base64String  = selectedImage.asUIImage().convertImageToBase64String()
                                let entityName =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "JournalImageEntity", in: backgroundContext)!
                                let journalImage = NSManagedObject(entity: entityName, insertInto: backgroundContext)
                                journalImage.setValue(base64String, forKeyPath: "storedImage")
                                journalImage.setValue(uuid, forKeyPath: "uuid")
                                try! backgroundContext.save()
                            }, completion:{
                                
                            })
                        }
```

And the extensions being called

```swift
extension View {
    // This function changes our View to UIView, then calls another function
    // to convert the newly-made UIView to a UIImage.
    public func asUIImage() -> UIImage {
        
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        
        controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(Int.max), width: 1, height: 1)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        
        let size = controller.sizeThatFits(in: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
        controller.view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        controller.view.sizeToFit()
        
        // here is the call to the function that converts UIView to UIImage: `.asUIImage()`
        let image = controller.view.asUIImage()
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        return image
    }
}

extension UIView {
    // This is the function to convert UIView to UIImage
    public func asUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Crash log
2022-06-22 18:52:45.600395+0200 HuntRegs[62861:7686003] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
Stack:(
0   CoreAutoLayout                      0x00007fff60b06f0c _AssertAutoLayoutOnAllowedThreadsOnly + 206
1   CoreAutoLayout                      0x00007fff60b0726c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 25
2   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff256440c6 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 822
3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff25654253 -[UIView(Internal) *addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2489
4   HuntRegs                            0x000000010379128d $s7SwiftUI4ViewP8HuntRegsE9asUIImageSo0G0CyF + 1421
5   HuntRegs                            0x0000000103137c7f $s8HuntRegs14AddJournalViewV4bodyQrvg7SwiftUI21ToolbarContentBuilderV10buildBlockyQrx_q_tAE0iJ0RzAeIR_r0_lFZQOy_AE0I9ItemGroupVyAE6ButtonVyAE4TextVGGAQQo_yXEfU9_APyXEfU0_yycfU_yycfU_Tf2nni_n + 671
6   HuntRegs                            0x00000001035b6995 $sSo17OS_dispatch_queueC8HuntRegsE10background5delayAD10completionySd_yycSgAGtFZyycfU* + 405
7   HuntRegs                            0x00000001030b94b8 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 40
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105040816 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105041a5b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105053d6f _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 880
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010505464e _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 196
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6fb0502e _pthread_wqthread + 256
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6fb03ffb start_wqthread + 15
)
2022-06-22 18:52:45.603898+0200 HuntRegs[62861:7686003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20406d44 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201a4a65 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreAutoLayout                      0x00007fff60b06fe4 -[NSISEngine tryToOptimizeReturningMutuallyExclusiveConstraints] + 0
3   CoreAutoLayout                      0x00007fff60b0726c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 25
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff256440c6 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 822
5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff25654253 -[UIView(Internal) *addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2489
6   HuntRegs                            0x000000010379128d $s7SwiftUI4ViewP8HuntRegsE9asUIImageSo0G0CyF + 1421
7   HuntRegs                            0x0000000103137c7f $s8HuntRegs14AddJournalViewV4bodyQrvg7SwiftUI21ToolbarContentBuilderV10buildBlockyQrx_q_tAE0iJ0RzAeIR_r0_lFZQOy_AE0I9ItemGroupVyAE6ButtonVyAE4TextVGGAQQo_yXEfU9_APyXEfU0_yycfU_yycfU_Tf2nni_n + 671
8   HuntRegs                            0x00000001035b6995 $sSo17OS_dispatch_queueC8HuntRegsE10background5delayAD10completionySd_yycSgAGtFZyycfU* + 405
9   HuntRegs                            0x00000001030b94b8 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 40
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105040816 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105041a5b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000105053d6f _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 880
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010505464e _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 196
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6fb0502e _pthread_wqthread + 256
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6fb03ffb start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/petervandeput/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HuntRegs-dgsnbdluljikcgfdfvaoamgthwtt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/petervandeput/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HuntRegs-dgsnbdluljikcgfdfvaoamgthwtt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 802.6 - Device: iPhone 13 (8D6A3EA4-D34E-45F0-A61C-9F5BA03A7894) - Runtime: iOS 15.4 (19E240) - DeviceType: iPhone 13

Comment: Could you share the (non-working) code you're currently trying? You're likely to get a better response if those answering have something to start with. Thanks

Comment: Please post the error with which your code is crashing. That would be very helpful.